# How to determine the SQL Server object name from object id and database id?

Tags: sql-server, object, sql-server-2000, metadata

I need the behaviour of SQL Server 2005 where function OBJECT_NAME takes two arguments, `obj id` and `db id`, while SQL Server 2000 takes only `obj id` so the execution must be in the context of the database to which inspected object belongs to.

Solution must be possible to implement in a function, so it can be used in a select query.

Comment: If you can assume nothing about the current database context (which is "USEd"), and if you do not have both object_id and db-id, you cannot identify the object. Will both be provided to the function call?

Comment: Yes, object_id and db_id will be provided to the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL 2005 and up it is of course trivial to do this. The problem is SQL 2000. I used 2000 a lot back when, but no longer have access to any installations of it; the rest of this is largely from memory, and may be inaccurate.

The key thing is how to retrieve data from a database other than the "current" database, when you cannot know what that other database (or databases) will be at the time the code is written. (Yes, the db_id parameter is very convenient!) For this problem and for similar problems, the general work-around is to create dynamic code, something like:

```
SET @Command = 'select name from ' + @dbname + '.dbo.sysobjects where object_id = ' + @ObjectId
EXECUTE (@Command)
```

The problem is, I'm pretty sure you can't run dynamic code within functions (or perhaps just within SQL 2000 functions).

You might have to resort to creating a temp table, populating it via dynamic query, and then using it within the "main" query you are trying to write. Psuedo code would  be like:

```
CREATE #TempTable
IF SQL2000 or earlier
    INSERT #TempTable EXECUTE (select data from TargetDb.dbo.sysobjects)
    --  Note that the entire insert may need to be in the dynamic statement
ELSE
    INSERT #TempTable SELECT [from query based on object_id]

SELECT [the data you need]
 from YourTable
  join #TempTable
```

Comment: Yep. You can't use dynamic SQL. You get the error "Only functions and extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function."

Comment: I have to foolishly mention I once read an article wherein some great brain embedded a call to xp_cmdshell within a function. Imagine shelling out, querying a website, and returning data to your query, once per row. Please, please don't do that!

Comment: Philip, you described the reasons why I asked that questions. I was prepared that there might not be a neat solution to that. I needed this to use with sp_lock result set, so the approach with creating temp table upfront (cursor through all DBs in the system and pooling all from sysobjects) might be a bit expensive especially  when called often, but definitely some way to go. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL 2008 and up, use:

```sql
OBJECT_NAME ( object_id [, database_id ] )
```

for example:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10
    object_schema_name(objectid, dbid) as [SchemaName], 
    object_name(objectid, dbid) as [ObjectName],
    e.*
    from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans P
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(P.plan_handle) E
```